# How can I simply this function?

Tags: python, function, simplify

I want to shorten and simplify my code, but I don't seem to get how to do it.

```
def draw_sky(canvas, width, height, interval=30):
    sky_width = width
    sky_height = height
    sky_bottom = height / 4
    color_sky_list = ["skyBlue4", "skyBlue3", "skyBlue2", "lightSkyBlue"]

    draw_rectangle(canvas, 0, sky_bottom + (interval*3), sky_width, sky_height, fill = color_sky_list[0], width=0)
    draw_rectangle(canvas, 0, sky_bottom + (interval*2), sky_width, sky_height-(interval*1), fill = color_sky_list[1], width=0)
    draw_rectangle(canvas, 0, sky_bottom + interval, sky_width, sky_height-(interval*2), fill = color_sky_list[2], width=0)
    draw_rectangle(canvas, 0, sky_bottom, sky_width, sky_height-(interval*3), fill = color_sky_list[3], width=0)
```

Comment: At first glance, looks like you can just get rid of the `sky_width` and `sky_height` local variables you define since they're just straight copies of the function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Replace tedious drawing with loop:

```
for i, color in enumerate(color_sky_list):
    draw_rectangle(canvas, 0, sky_bottom + interval * (3 - i), sky_width, sky_height - interval * i, fill=color, width=0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't used the enumerate function before. This is of big help!